# A way to render a div block in Angular unit testt

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Hi I am trying to unit test my Angular front-end and stuck with a problem. My front-end dynamically renders some div blocks and lines can be drawn from one to another div block on click(). Those div blocks rendered dynamically, so you can generate more as you use the app, but that is part of the other function. So how would I render those divs in my unit test. Or is there some other way to test this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do logic to prepare a component to be tested and then trigger the rendering.

```js
it(`renders toggle after click`, async () => {
    component.handleClick();
    
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenRenderingDone();

    const toggle = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#toggle'));
    expect(toggle).toBeTruthy();
});
```